# Using an annotation not on an map but on an image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I want to use annotations, normally used on maps, on a large image.

It's a sub class of UIView, but the docs don't mention it's use outside of the MapKit.

Is this possible? If it's not, are there any known workarounds?

Comment: This is something you can achieve by creating a custom subclass of `UIView` but annotation serve a specific purpose on a map. How do you want to use it on an image?

Comment: I want to be able to make an annotation and add a note to a specifc point on an image.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible to use an MKAnnotationView outside a map - you'll have to implement your own annotation view. MKAnnotationView requires an object which conforms to [MKAnnotation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotation_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/MKAnnotation) to provide it coordinate information (CLLocationCoordinate2D) about where to display. Those coordinates are not CGPoints, so you won't be able to fake it on a view.

On iPad there is a [UIPopoverController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIPopoverController_class/Reference/Reference.html), which looks very similar to an annotation, and can be displayed on any view. Note that UIPopoverController is not available on any device but iPad.

Comment: its not the look im trying to mimic, its the functionality of the annotation. (and yes its for a iPad).